# Simple WCF queryable design

Tags: wcf, rest

I have been trying to figure this out, but was not able to find any examples suggesting this.

```
class SomeClass
{
  public int Field1;
  public int Field2;
  public int Field3;
  public int Field4;
  public int Field5;
  public int Field6;
  public int Field7;
  public int Field8;
}
```

If I had the above class in a WCF service and I wanted to expose a way to query a massive list of SomeClass items by any combination of fields. How would I do that? Would I need to write 2^8=256 methods?

If I also created a rest service would I also have to have 256 methods?

If the list is too large to entirely send then how do you design a queryable interface for the WCF service?

**Edit**: I am curious if there is a difference in the SOAP vs REST solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you design a queryable
>   interface for the WCF service?

You don't. WCF since has to work through WSDL does not have the flexibility to do this. You can try serialising your query and pass it across the wire but that is not a trivial task.

Comment: Does OData allow you to do something like I am describing?